# how to know when that a package has been corrected bugs

Tags: 14.04

Last week I upgraded ubuntu studio 14.04
My operating system is:

```
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
3.13.0-77-lowlatency
```

On last Friday package lbnl and I had to downgraded this package
and execute:

```
sudo apt-mark hold libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200
```

Today the software update give me this information:[image]

How to know that this bug was corrected?

Comment: Run `apt-get changelog packagename` to see the changelog.

Comment: Sorry, which bug?

Comment: Unless you are actively testing something in the proposed pocket because you have experienced a bug and are verifying the fix, you really should not enable the proposed pocket for updates on your system.

Comment: I agree with @dobey - more so on ubuntu studio. When doing av production, I value stability over the latest greatest package. If you find a bug - File a bug report on LP and subscribe to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should search and monitor bug report on the software upstream (developer who provide the software), or just report it yourself. Or you can check software changelog or release note (One of them https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuStudio).

Other than that, I think, you should try to install it and downgrade if the bug exists.

Comment: And file a bug report .... As far as developers are concerned, no bug report no problem. No bug report == no fix.

Comment: OK! the following list show packages with bug: libnl-3-200
libnl-genl-3-200
libnl-route-3-200

Comment: These packages break network-manager. But I'm confused. When the update or upgrade list packages that can be installed (new versions), users do not know if they are tested packages or proposed packages, then the question is: is  updated-manager a safe method for a newbye?